# Check if a given username is taken on Facebook

Tags: ruby, facebook

How to check if a username is already in use on Facebook?

My solution was trying to access `http://www.facebook.com/USER` and check the http headers (200 = OK; 404 = NOT FOUND). I could use this code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'

def remote_file_exists?(url,httpcode)
  url = URI.parse(url)
  Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    return http.head(url.request_uri).code == httpcode
  end
end
```

The problem is that Facebook always returns 302 (Found), then redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/USER`.

I can require `net/https` and create a new function:

```
def https_url_exists? (url,httpcode)
  url = URI.parse(url)
  net = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) 
  net.use_ssl = true
  net.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  net.start do |http|
    return (http.head(url.request_uri).code == httpcode)
  end
end
```

Now the problem is that some users use dots on their usernames. For example, username might be user.name. Facebook use redirections for this.

**What's the best way to check if USERNAME exists on facebook? How to get USER.NAME if USERNAME redirects to it?**

Comment: There's a big difference between checking if a user is on Facebook OR a username is "used" on Facebook! which one you need?

Comment: @ifaour I want to check if a username is used on facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `https://graph.facebook.com/username`.  This will return a json response with info to see if it exists as well as enough information to identify it as a user or page.

Once you have a valid user you can get user name First,Last info using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}?fields=first_name,last_name
```

Comment: Great! I don't need to use SSL this way. Thanks!